# I assambled rear wheel hub, but now rear wheel is not turning freely

Tags: wheels, repair, hub

I disassambled/assambled rear wheel hub, but now rear wheel is not turning freely, what have i done wrong?

Comment: After you solve the problem, please come back to tell us what the problem was!

Answer (score 6):

You likely tightened the cones too tight.  Read up on the proper procedure for cone adjustment and be sure to grease it up well.

http://sheldonbrown.com/cone-adjustment.html

OR

http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/hub-overhaul-and-adjustment

Comment: See related question: 
http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3456/trouble-getting-the-right-cup-and-cone-hub-adjustment

Comment: Also, it is possible that some part, usually the small tin rings that aid in waterproofing, got misaligned. But indeed, by far, the most probable cause are too-tight cones.

Answer (score 1):

There are unfortunately a dozen different things that can go wrong.  First on the list, as mentioned, is over-tightened cones.  But beyond that it's easy to get a spacer in the wrong place to that, eg, the freehub rubs against the hub body, or you can simply get a foreign object (eg a washer) jammed in between components somewhere.